# Add spring-integration inbound-channel-adapter after the application has started

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring-integration channel hooked up to a service-activator using the XML configuration.  I've attached an sftp inbound-channel-adapter to the same channel.  This is working quite well.

I would like to allow my clients to add/remove SFTP inbound-channel-adapters to the channel through my web interface, but instantiating spring-integration components appears to be fairly tightly coupled to the XML Spring context (see org.springframework.integration.sftp.config.SftpInboundChannelAdapterParser).

Is there a way to add/remove SFTP inbound-channel-adapters after the application has started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial task. 
All Spring Integration components are Spring beans, at least.
So, if you want to do something with Spring at runtime you should Application Context, who provides Dependency Injection features.
I suggest to take a look into this sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp
It demonstrates some dynamic registration technique.

Comment: FYI, that sample is for an outbound adapter. On the inbound side, you need to make the adapter's application context a child of the main context, so you can wire the adapter to a channel in the main context (child contexts can 'see' beans in parent contexts). Simply set the main context as the parent argument when constructing the adapter's context and reference a channel in the main context.

Comment: This worked for me using the Grails 2.2.3 BeanBuilder.  I created separate application contexts programmatically, and then tracked them as the example suggested.